# Objects.equals() vs StringUtils.isNotBlank() in Java

Tags: java, equals, string-comparison

Could you please explain me if there is a difference between the functionality of the following codes?
I know that the Objects.equals() checks for the NULL value first and then compares the two strings.

I have the following conditions and I want to know which one is more practical.

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(str1) && str1.equals(str2)) {// do sth}
```

or is it enough to say:

```
if (Objects.equals(str1,str2)) {// do sth}
```

Thanks

Comment: letter will (potentially?) pass `"".equals("")` while first one wont

Comment: ..and also if `str1` and `str2` are both null `Objects.equals()` gives true (probably not what you want!).

Comment: Which `StringUtils` do you use? How `StringUtils.isNotBlank(str1)` make sence here, you can use `str1 != null` or simple `StringUtils.equals(str1, str2)`

Comment: I don't understand how you can begin to ask about the differences between a method that compares two objects with another method that only looks at one object.

Comment: @Jens good question, I assumed it was the Apache Commons version as that seems to be the most popular one, and added the tag (prematurely), but of course there are others and possibly even a class in the OP's own project.

Comment: @user207421  I explained the comparision in the form of these two conditions. why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apache Commons method [StringUtils.isNotBlank](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-) will return false if the string is null, empty, or contains only whitespace. There will be differences in the following situations:

| str1 | str2 | Results(1st code/2nd code) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | false/true |
| "" | "" | false/true |
| " " | " " | false/true |